# Javafx mvvmfx textarea append

Tags: java, javafx, append, textarea, mvvmfx

I'm having an issue with my JavaFX application. Problem is that I can't use append function, only setText. Why this is a problem is because auto scroll is not working without append. What is the way to update or auto-scroll my TextArea each time new text appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX component [`TextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) inherits the method [`setText(String value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setText-java.lang.String-) from [`TextInputControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html) and its documentations sais:

> Sets the value of the property text.

which means the text is set as a new one. To just insert a new line (update, append) the text, you have to use the method [`appendText(String value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-) inherited as well.

> Appends a sequence of characters to the content.

Both of the input `String value`'s must be not `null`.

To scroll to the end, you have to implement a listener which is triggered by any text change (`setText()`, `appendText()`) and perform the scroll using the method [`setScrollTop(double value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#setScrollTop-double-). The parameter `double value` is the number of pixels by which the content is vertically scrolled - using the largest possible double value `Double.MAX_VALUE` makes it scroll to the end.

```
textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  
    textArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
});
```